# PHP syntax and programmatical grammar explanation

Tags: php, syntax, foreach, expression

I have a piece of code that needed to be directly translated from PHP to vb.net/C#. I would like to ask, what do these next expressions meant in simple English terms? Maybe a little bit (or more) of an elaboration would be nice. Here goes.

```
1.    foreach ($_SESSION[''] as $variable1 => $variable2) {}
2.    $variable .= <<<EOD{ "a":"1", "b":"2","c":"3" },EOD
```

I would like to understand what they meant. And maybe a little advice on how to apply it in asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### foreach()

`foreach()` loops through an array and assigns successive elements to the specified variable.  For instance, your example, the variable `$_SESSION` is looped through, with the index (the part in the brackets) being assigned to `$variable1` and the value being assigned to `$variable2`.  If your array looked like this:

```
$_SESSION = array(
    'red'  => 'first element',
    'blue' => 'second element'
);
```

Then your `foreach()` would loop twice.  The first time, `$variable1` would equal "red" and `$variable2` would equal "first element".  The second time, `$variable1` would equal "blue" and `$variable2` would equal "second element".

### HEREDOC

For the second part, there are multiple things that need explanation.  First, `.=` is a concatenation.  So:

```
$variable .= 'value';
```

is the same as:

```
$variable = $variable . 'value';
```

Next, we have something called a HEREDOC.  This is a way of assigning a string value to a variable by encapsulating it between two arbitrary strings.  So:

```
$variable .= <<<EOD
{ "a":"1", "b":"2","c":"3" },
EOD;
```

is the same as:

```
$variable .= '{ "a":"1", "b":"2","c":"3" },'
```

Within the example you've provided, it doesn't make much sense to use HEREDOC format, because everything easily fits on one line.  But imagine something like this:

```
$variable = <<<TEXT
Some line of text with a " mark.
Another line of text with a ' mark.
TEXT;
```

This can be easier to read and maintain than the following:

```
$variable = "Some line of text with a \" mark.\nAnother line of text with a ' mark.";
```

With HEREDOC, the string ends when the delimiter you've chosen begins on a new line all on its own starting at the far left.

Comment: you'd better use associative array example, because $_SESSION[''] reffered

Comment: thank you so much for this to the both of you. i understood this now much better.

Answer (score 1):

Simple explaination

- `Foreach`  - loop to easily iterate over arrays works from first array element to last array element. check foreach reference from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) it is very vast
- `$_SESSION['']` is a super global variable in php whose scope is available in endless sections of the code. session saves the data in form of array so the loop will work for each [session array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variable.
- `$variable` is a local variable you created which can either be string or integer, type casting is automatic in php.
- `.=` is string concatenation which appends new content to existing string content. ex :

  ```
  $string = "first_Name ";
  $string .= "Last_Name";

  echo $string; // output - first_Name  Last_Name
  ```
- `<<<EOD` - there are four types of strings available in php. They are single quotes `(')`, double quotes `(")` and `Nowdoc (<<<'EOD')` and `heredoc(<<<EOD)` strings. see about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: thank you so much for this to the both of you. i understood this now much better.